# Error 415 Api Rest Spring Boot y Angular (formato Json enviado no es el correcto)

Tags: angular, spring-boot

Buenas gracias por leer mi pregunta espero me puedan ayudar, necesito crear este formato Json con angular usando form builder y un mat-select en la interface, el array de proveedores es dinamico ya que depende del numero de proveedores que tenga un producto a ingresar...

```
    {
        "idProducto": 0,
        "categoria": {
            "idCategoria": 1,
            "categoria": "Fasa"
        },
        "seVendePor": "Bulto",
        "nombreP": "Raula dejada",
        "pCompra": 917.0,
        "pVenta": 1050.0,
        "iva": 0.16,
        "stock": 4.0,
        "codBarras": "t",
        "proveedores": [
            {
               "idProveedor": 1,
                "nombre": "Najumy metalera carreto",
                "direccion": "Av. Atenas Veracruzana # 227",
                "telefono": "2282816969",
                "correo": "tonermed@hotmail.com"
            },
            {
                "idProveedor": 2,
                "nombre": "Pedrina Balcazar",
                "direccion": "Calle Antonio lopez de Lara #27 Col Rev. Xalapa Ve...",
                "telefono": "2282816969",
                "correo": "tonermed@hotmail.com"
            },
            {
                "idProveedor": 3,
                "nombre": "Cliente general",
                "direccion": "Calle Antonio lopez de Lara #27 Col Rev. Xalapa Ve...",
                "telefono": "2282816969",
                "correo": "tonermed@hotmail.com"
            }

        ]
}
```

Este es my TS

```
formularioProductos: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    categoria: this.fb.group(
      {
        idCategoria: [''],
        categoria: ['']
      }
    ),
    seVendePor: ['', [Validators.required]],
    nombreP: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(25)]],
    pCompra: ['', [Validators.required]],
    pVenta: ['', [Validators.required]],
    iva: ['', [Validators.required]],
    stock: ['', [Validators.required]],
    codBarras: ['', [Validators.required]],
    proveedores: this.fb.array([])
  });

     private createItem(item:Proveedor): FormGroup {
        return this.fb.group([{
          idProveedor: item.idProveedor,
          nombre: item.nombre,
          direccion: item.direccion,
          telefono: item.telefono,
          correo: item.correo
        }]);
      }
    
      obtenerProveeSelected() {
        if (this.selectedProvee.length == 0) {
          console.log('mat-select vacio')
        } else {
          this.cargando = true;
          this.serviceprovee.listarProveedoresXids(this.selectedProvee).subscribe({
            next: res => {
              this.vectorProveedores = res;
              let proveeArray: any = [];
              for (let item of this.vectorProveedores) {
                proveeArray.push(this.createItem(item));
              }
              this.formularioProductos.controls['proveedores'] = this.fb.array(proveeArray);
              this.cargando = false;
            },
            error: (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
              alert(err.message);
              this.cargando = false;
            }
          })
        }
      }
    
    
      guardar() {
    
        if (this.formularioProductos.invalid) {
          this.formularioProductos.markAllAsTouched();
          return;
        };
        this.cargando = true;
        let c: Categoria = {
          idCategoria: this.idCategoria,
          categoria: ""
        }
        this.formularioProductos.get('categoria')?.patchValue(c);
        this.obtenerProveeSelected();
    
        if(this.formularioProductos.get('proveedores')?.value == 0){
          console.log('Array proveedores vacio');
        }else{
          console.log(this.formularioProductos.value);
        }
        
        
        /* this.serviceProduct.agregarProducto(this.formularioProductos.value).subscribe({
          next:() =>{
           this.reportarCierre();
            this.cargando = false;
          },
          error:(err: HttpErrorResponse) =>{
            alert(err.message); 
            this.cargando = false;
          }
        }); */    
        /* this.limpiar(); */
      }
```

Lo que hago esque obtengo los ids de los proveedores selecionados en el mat-select y hago una consulta a mi back para obtener los datos completos de estos porque en la configuracion many to many en spring boot si solo mando los id del proveedor se borran los datos de estos, entonces despues de obtenerlos los meto a mi variable proveedores del formGroup productos y al imprimirlo en consola me sale el array de proveedores anidado, pero al darle guardar me sale error 415(que el formato de la data enviada es inaceptable) me guie de este ejemplo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58113681/reactive-forms-form-builder-dynamically-set-array-size-in-the-form-model

Answer (score 0):

Por si a alguien le sirve, mi error estaba en mi api en la configuracion
many to many tenia la anotacion @Trasient en mi entidad Proveedor paraque al consultar los proveedores no me devolviera todo el arreglo de productos relacionados, la cambie por @jsonIgnore y ya no me arrojo ningun error asi me quedo el formulario con un group y un array anidados

Entidad Proveedor Spring Boot

```
 @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "proveedores", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnore
   /*  @Transient */
    private List<Producto> productos = new ArrayList<>();
```

Mi TS

```
obtenerCategoria(){
    let c: Categoria = {
      idCategoria: this.idCategoria,
      categoria: ""
    }
      this.formularioProductos.get('categoria')?.patchValue(c);
  }

  obtenerProveeSelected() {
   if (this.selectedProvee.length == 0) {
      console.log('mat-select vacio')
     } else {
      this.cargando = true;
      this.serviceprovee.listarProveedoresXids(this.selectedProvee).subscribe({
        next: res => {
          this.vectorProveedores = res;
          let newArray: Proveedor[] = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < this.vectorProveedores.length; i++) {
            newArray.push({
              idProveedor: this.vectorProveedores[i].idProveedor,
              nombre: this.vectorProveedores[i].nombre,
              direccion: this.vectorProveedores[i].direccion,
              telefono: this.vectorProveedores[i].telefono,
              correo: this.vectorProveedores[i].correo
            });
          }
          this.formularioProductos.controls['proveedores'] = this.fb.array(newArray);
          this.guardar();
          this.cargando = false;          
        },
        error: (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          alert(err.message);
          this.cargando = false;
        }
      });
    }
  }


 guardar() {
  
  if(this.formularioProductos.invalid) {
      this.formularioProductos.markAllAsTouched();
      return;
    }
    this.cargando = true;
      this.obtenerCategoria();
      console.log(this.formularioProductos.value)
      this.serviceProduct.agregarProducto(this.formularioProductos.value).subscribe({
        next: () => {
          this.reportarCierre();
          this.cargando = false;
        },
        error: (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          alert(err.message);
          this.cargando = false;
        }
      });
      this.limpiar();
  }
```